# How to find the immutable fields in a kubernetes workload spec?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

Is there a way to find the immutable fields in the workload's spec? I could see there are few fields mentioned as immutable in some of the workload resource documentation, But for example in [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) is not clear which are immutable fields. Is there a better way to find out?

Sorry, I am not so familiar with reading the Kubernetes API spec yet, I couldn't figure it out. Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance, Naga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the community.

Unfortunately there's no such list with all `immutable fields` combined in one place.

There are two options:

1. As you started through reading documentation and see if this is specified explicitly.
2. Start with `kubernetes API` description. You can find it here: [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#-strong-api-overview-strong-). This is also available in more human-readable form [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/). Same applies here - it's not specified explicitly whether field is immutable or not.

For instance all objects and fields for `statefulset` can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#statefulset-v1-apps).

(I will update it if I find a better way)

Comment: This is mildly helpful, basically, it depends on lots of if statement logic / edge cases. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/validation/validation.go

Answer (score 0):

One easy way of finding immutable fields from the documentation is to check condig connector api resources. For example [here](https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/reference/resource-docs/iam/iampartialpolicy) you can search for "immutable" keyword and see all immutable fields for given resource.
If you need to find immutable fields of other or all resources then you have to go one by one I'm afraid.
Hope this helps.